# How do I find gaps between ranges?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, range

Let's use this examples of ranges:

```js
const ranges = [
  [
    0,
    10,
  ],
  [
    20,
    30,
  ],
  [
    40,
    50,
  ],
];
```

I want to find missing ranges between two range values, e.g. If input was `[-10, 60]`, then the expected output must be:

```js
const islands = [
  [
    -10,
    -1,
  ],
  [
    11,
    19,
  ],
  [
    31,
    39,
  ],
  [
    51,
    60,
  ],
];
```

I tried searching for "disjoint ranges" and "non-intersecting ranges" and similar keywords. This seems like a problem that would have been solved a million times before. Maybe I am just using wrong keywords.

Comment: While I would _like_ to see more information about the expectations here (e.g. how should your code know that each range has a size/length/whatever of 10?), and of course we always want to see OP make an effort at solving the problem themselves first, I don't think this should necessarily be _closed_ for lack of it (and certainly not deleted). Consequently, I'm voting to reopen this.

Answer (score 2):

One of the main data structures for finding intersections in intervals is [Interval Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#With_an_Interval). You can construct an interval tree over `ranges` and follow intersections of the input range with them by query on the tree. Then, sweep from left to right of the input range to find gaps.

You can find many implementations for the interval tree in javascript for example [this one](https://github.com/shinout/interval-tree).

Answer (score 1):

```js
const findMissing = (arr, ranges) => {
  [min, max] = arr;
  return ranges.reduce((acc, a, i) => {
    if (a[0] < min) return acc;
    if (min < a[0]) acc.push([min, a[0] - 1]);
    if (i == ranges.length - 1 && max > a[1]) acc.push([a[1] + 1, max]);
    min = a[1] + 1;
    return acc
  }, [])

}

let ranges = [ [2, 10], [5, 7], [40, 50] ]
console.log(findMissing([-10, 60], ranges));

ranges = [ [0, 10],[20, 30],[40, 50]];
console.log(findMissing([-10, 60], ranges));
```

Comment: @Gajus It is not correct. You can find that it is not working for the following case for example:

`const ranges = [
  [2, 10],
  [5, 7],
  [40, 50]
];`

and input range `[-10, 60]`

Comment: @Gajus It is more complicated than this. Because intervals can have partially overlap or even completely covered by others.

Comment: @OmG - So the expected result would be [-10,1], [ 9,6], [8,39] ... ?

Comment: The expected result is `[-10, 1], [11, 39], [51, 60]`.

Comment: Also, please note that it is an example. There are many complex cases for intervals overlapping that cannot be handle manually. Definitely, to deal with them, you need a proper data structure like an interval tree.

Comment: @OmG is right. I've built some test cases to show where this is failing. https://gist.github.com/gajus/077eba039041e9c4dcba725868031460

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to write an implementation that covers all edge cases that I could think of.

I am sharing this in case no one else provides an authoritative answer (I expect there to be a smarter solution):

```js
const getGaps = (ranges: RangesType): RangesType => {
  const gaps = [];

  // $FlowFixMe
  for (const index in ranges) {
    const start = ranges[Number(index)][1];
    const end = ranges[Number(index) + 1]?.[0];

    if (start < end) {
      gaps.push([
        start + 1,
        end - 1,
      ]);
    }
  }

  return gaps;
};

const getMissingRanges = (ranges: RangesType, from: number, to: number): RangesType => {
  if (ranges.length === 0) {
    return [
      [
        from,
        to,
      ],
    ];
  }

  const gaps = [
    [
      Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
      ranges[0][0] - 1,
    ],
    ...getGaps(
      ranges,
    ),
    [
      ranges[ranges.length - 1][1] + 1,
      Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
    ],
  ];

  return gaps
    .filter((gap) => {
      return isRangeOverlapping(gap, [from, to]);
    })
    .map((gap) => {
      return [
        Math.max(gap[0], from),
        Math.min(gap[1], to),
      ];
    });
};
```

Comment: This passes all the test cases described in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/gajus/077eba039041e9c4dcba725868031460).